# Show span of subset equal to vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a vector space $V$ such that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$ and $span(S_1)=V$, then $span(S_2)=V$.

I already proved that given $S_1 \subseteq S_2$, $span(S_1) \subseteq span(S_2)$.

If I want to show $span(S_2)=V$, would I need to show they are mutually inclusive? I already know that $V \subseteq span(S_2)$ from the previous proof, is that sufficient? Or would I need to show $span(S_2) \subseteq V$ as well?

Comment: Do you see why $\mathrm{span}(S_2)\subseteq V$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, I do now. Every vector in $S_2$ is in $V$, because  $S_2$ is a subset of $V$. I overlooked that fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span of a subset $S\subset V$ can be defined as the intersection of all subspaces in $V$ containing $S$.  Since $V$ is a subspace containing $S$, it follows that span$(S)\subset V$.